# ansible: when condition with var from include

Tags: ansible

With ansible 1.9.2 I have a role with::

```
- include: snippet.yml repo=rep1
- include: snippet.yml repo=rep2
- include: snippet.yml repo=rep2
```

in `snippet.yml` I have::

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg='hello'
  when: rep1 == {{ repo }}
```

But I get this error message::

```
fatal: [vagrant] => error while evaluating conditional: rep1 == rep1

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

When I use the fist syntax proposed by @arbabnazar::

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg='hello'
  when: "rep1 == {{ repo }}"
```

I get this error::

```
TASK: [stack | debug] *******************************************
fatal: [vagrant] => error while evaluating conditional: rep1 == rep1

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

With the second syntax proposed by @arbabnazar::

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg='hello'
  when: "rep1 in {{ repo }}"
```

I get this error::

```
TASK: [stack | debug] *******************************************
fatal: [vagrant] => error while evaluating conditional: rep1 in rep1

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please check it now. it's working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg='hello'
  when: repo  == "repo1"
```

Comment: I try your proposal without success (and update the question)